# How should use variables?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

If I add variables(build stage), the stages does not work. Where exactly am I going wrong. If remove the variables under only `variables` section, it runs.

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Build is running"
  only:
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
      - requirements.txt
      - ./configs/*
    variables:
      - $BUILD == "True"

development:
  stage: development
  script:
    - echo "development"
  except:
    variables:
      - $BUILD == "False"

development_build:
  stage: development_build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD OK"
  rules:
    - if: $BUILD == "True"
      when: always
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariables--exceptvariables) mentions

> ### `only:variables` / `except:variables`
>
> Use the `only:variables` or `except:variables` keywords to control when to add jobs to a pipeline, based on the status of CI/CD variables.
>
> Keyword type: Job keyword. You can use it only as part of a job.
>
> Possible inputs: An array of **[CI/CD variable expressions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#cicd-variable-expressions)**.

First: try and use [`rules:if`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif) to see if the issue persists.

```yaml
job1:
  variables:
    VAR1: "variable1"
  script:
    - echo "Test variable comparison"
  rules:
    - if: $VAR1 == "variable1"
```

Second, try with a different variable name, in case `BUILD` is somehow reserved.

Check also where you have BUILD defined (is there a [`workflow:rules:variables`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrulesvariables) section?)